# Multiple event emitters are not firing correctly - Angular 2

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I have 2 event emitters

```
public event1: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
public event2: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

both are defined as `outputs` on the component

```
@Component({
    ...
    outputs: ['event1', 'event2']
})
```

I am trying to call it after a click event like

```
this.event1.emit();
setTimeout(() => {
    //do your operation
    this.event2.emit();
}, 10000);
```

One event needs to be emitted 10 seconds after the other and I am using the setTimeout to emit the second event. The issue is only 1 of these events is getting called at once, for example if I comment the `event1.emit`, `event2` is correctly emitted but if I uncomment it, `event1` is emitted and second one is ignored. I have tried to do it with one `emitter` but even in that case, only 1 call is initiated and other one is ignored. I don't want to use observable for this, really confused about this behavior.

Edit: This is how I am calling it from the parent component

```
<auction-remaining-time ... (event1)="event1Called($event)" (event2)="event2Called($event)"></auction-remaining-time>
```

Comment: Can you show how you are using this component? Btw `EventEmitter` is built on top of `Observable`

Comment: @OsmanCea I have added the code for how I am using this in the parent component above

Comment: There might be something wrong with you click  event handler then, I have a little set up in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-output-decorator) and it works as expected

Comment: Well yes, strange its working there! I will try to investigate it and see what is going wrong! Thanks :)

Comment: If I just emit event1 in the timeout and event2 outside, it works but doesn't when I reverse the order! Really strange

Comment: can you share more of your relevant code? perhaps uploading a repo or whatever

Comment: @AliBaig I have the same strange issue today. did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @webpassion101 I'm not sure how I got around it back then but I think I was using an *ngIf on the parent component and after receiving the first event, I was setting the condition of that *ngIf to true which was removing the component and therefore the second event was never being called.

Comment: @AliBaig wow, it was the same issue for me. You're a savior!! THANK YOU :)

Comment: @AliBaig, OMG thanks God that I've read you comment